# Make manually installed programs visible in system(whisker menu)

Tags: arch-linux, path, xfce

I have manually installed aptana Studio under /opt/aptana, I have created a symlink under /usr/bin, but how can I make aptana visible in whisker menu, is there a systemwide daemon or config file where i can register aptana, similiar to $PATH? 
Btw im using arch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to create a `.desktop` file in either `~/.local/share/applications/` (for a single-user) or `/usr/share/applications/` (for every user). Any `.desktop` files in either of these locations will show up in your Whisker Menu (and also the default XFCE applications menu).

You can read about the syntax of a `.desktop` file [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_entries).

As far as setting up the application in your `$PATH`, you've stated that you made a symlink to the program in `/usr/bin`. Your program is already covered; `/usr/bin` is already set up in your `$PATH` by the system.